# How to build software like billing software and invoice with modern gui

Tags: python, user-interface, software-design, user-experience

How do I get started with building software like billing software or invoice maker. I made them
with tkinter but I want them in attractive modern GUI . I don't want them to be web based.
if its not possible with python I can learn other way too. but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar issues regarding the aesthetic of a GUI. Perhaps have a look at a good few examples of GUI framework programs here:

https://www.digitaldesignjournal.com/python-gui-framework/

Although they are Tkinter based and probably the same structure overall. It might be a good option for your needs, as I understand.

Please also note that the limitations of GUI aesthetic is also limited in plain `tkinter` as far as I am concerned.

You can also have a look at tkinter.ttk as follows:

https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/ttk-style/

I have played around a lot with the `ttk` attributes and it might be a good option to investigate. I find that python is a much easier language to adapt to rather than learn another language solemnly for better GUI aesthetic. (Although important)

I trust that this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt). Personally, I find that applications made with PyQt generally have a modern feel. Below you can se an example application I found on a [PyQt tutorial](https://build-system.fman.io/pyqt5-tutorial):

[image]